# Can't call gsutil config in google cloud sdk?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have downloaded latest google cloud sdk.

Now I want to use gsutil. Whatever command I call on gsutil, I get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\bootstrapping\g
sutil.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Programs\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\bootstrapping\g
sutil.py", line 55, in main
    boto_path = os.pathsep.join(path_parts)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 9: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

How to change encoding of gsutil.py?

Comment: Is your home directory (or gcloud config directory) path has some non-ascii characters? You can run `gcloud feedback` command to file a bug report about this issue.

Comment: Path to `gsutil` is ``D:\Programs\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin

Comment: That is where the `gcloud` and `gsutil` are installed, but these tools store per user configuration in different directory. This is ussually `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\gcloud`. So if your username has non-ascii characters that could cause this issue as well. But other things could go wrong as well.