# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, gsutil

I have not programmed on python. I first time see such code.
My python `gsutil` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2013 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#

"""A convenience wrapper for starting gsutil."""

import os
import sys


import bootstrapping
from googlecloudsdk.core import config
from googlecloudsdk.core import metrics
from googlecloudsdk.core import properties
from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import gce as c_gce


def _MaybeAddBotoOption(args, section, name, value):
  if value is None:
    return
  args.append('-o')
  args.append('{section}:{name}={value}'.format(
      section=section, name=name, value=value))


def main():
  """Launches gsutil."""

  project, account = bootstrapping.GetActiveProjectAndAccount()
  pass_credentials = (
      properties.VALUES.core.pass_credentials_to_gsutil.GetBool() and
      not properties.VALUES.auth.disable_credentials.GetBool())

  if pass_credentials and account not in c_gce.Metadata().Accounts():
    gsutil_path = config.Paths().LegacyCredentialsGSUtilPath(account)

    # Allow gsutil to only check for the '1' string value, as is done
    # with regard to the 'CLOUDSDK_WRAPPER' environment variable.
    os.environ['CLOUDSDK_CORE_PASS_CREDENTIALS_TO_GSUTIL'] = '1'

    boto_config = os.environ.get('BOTO_CONFIG', '')
    boto_path = os.environ.get('BOTO_PATH', '')

    # We construct a BOTO_PATH that tacks the refresh token config
    # on the end.
    if boto_config:
      boto_path = os.pathsep.join([boto_config, gsutil_path])
    elif boto_path:
      boto_path = os.pathsep.join([boto_path, gsutil_path])
    else:
      path_parts = ['/etc/boto.cfg',
                    os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.boto')),
                    gsutil_path]
      boto_path = os.pathsep.join(path_parts)

    if 'BOTO_CONFIG' in os.environ:
      del os.environ['BOTO_CONFIG']
    os.environ['BOTO_PATH'] = boto_path

  # Tell gsutil whether gcloud analytics collection is enabled.
  os.environ['GA_CID'] = metrics.GetCIDIfMetricsEnabled()

  args = []

  _MaybeAddBotoOption(args, 'GSUtil', 'default_project_id', project)
  if pass_credentials and account in c_gce.Metadata().Accounts():
    # Tell gsutil to look for GCE service accounts.
    _MaybeAddBotoOption(args, 'GoogleCompute', 'service_account', 'default')

  proxy_params = properties.VALUES.proxy
  proxy_address = proxy_params.address.Get()
  if proxy_address:
    _MaybeAddBotoOption(args, 'Boto', 'proxy', proxy_address)
    _MaybeAddBotoOption(args, 'Boto', 'proxy_port', proxy_params.port.Get())
    _MaybeAddBotoOption(args, 'Boto', 'proxy_rdns', proxy_params.rdns.GetBool())
    _MaybeAddBotoOption(args, 'Boto', 'proxy_user', proxy_params.username.Get())
    _MaybeAddBotoOption(args, 'Boto', 'proxy_pass', proxy_params.password.Get())
  disable_ssl = properties.VALUES.auth.disable_ssl_validation.GetBool()
  _MaybeAddBotoOption(args, 'Boto', 'https_validate_certificates',
                      None if disable_ssl is None else not disable_ssl)
  _MaybeAddBotoOption(args, 'Boto', 'ca_certificates_file',
                      properties.VALUES.core.custom_ca_certs_file.Get())

  bootstrapping.ExecutePythonTool('platform/gsutil', 'gsutil', *args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  version = bootstrapping.GetFileContents('platform/gsutil', 'VERSION')
  bootstrapping.CommandStart('gsutil', version=version)

  blacklist = {
      'update': 'To update, run: gcloud components update',
  }

  bootstrapping.CheckForBlacklistedCommand(sys.argv, blacklist, warn=True,
                                           die=True)
  # Don't call bootstrapping.PreRunChecks because anonymous access is
  # supported for some endpoints. gsutil will output the appropriate
  # error message upon receiving an authentication error.
  bootstrapping.CheckUpdates('gsutil')
  main()
```

When I run it from command line as:

```
gsutil config
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\bootstrapping\g
sutil.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Programs\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\bootstrapping\g
sutil.py", line 55, in main
    boto_path = os.pathsep.join(path_parts)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 9: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

How to fix it? Line that gives error is:

```
boto_path = os.pathsep.join(path_parts)
```

Comment: Some comments related to this issue is posted on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471114/).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are running this snippet with python3, but this is only for python2.

I think you have already known there are two incompatible python versions right?

Comment: I installed google cloud sdk. And try to create bucket there. I use `gsutil` tool for this. But when I call it it goves me error.

Comment: @JaySmith In your terminal, run command `python --version`. If it gives you something like `Python 3.5.2`, you are using python3. You need python2 to run `gsutil` tool.